# Matplotlib in Python cannot save tiff

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using WinPython 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit system, with Python 3.4 and matplotlib 1.5.1. I cannot save my plot in tiff format, such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
fig.savefig('mpl_tiff.tif', dpi=300)
```

It would say:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/mpl_tiff.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-6a562331465e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/mpl_tiff.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads')

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 807, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 95, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/mpl_tiff.py", line 11, in <module>
    fig.savefig('mpl_tiff.tif', dpi=300)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1565, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 196, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2232, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 594, in print_tif
    dpi=dpi)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1666, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1325, in _save
    offset = ifd.save(fp)

  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 606, in save
    if len(data) <= 4:

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Could anyone please provide a solution? Thanks!

Shawn

PS: I read from googling that this might be the issue: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1524

But the solution is still unclear.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with [Pillow 3.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.1.0).

Comment: @cgohlke Thank you Chris! Sorry for my naive-ness, but my mistake was that before upgrading to pillow 3.1.0 in windows I did not uninstall pillow 3.0.0 first. Thanks! Would you bother to write the answer saying updating to Pillow 3.1.0 will fix this? I will accept it and it might help others. Otherwise, I can write an answer if you like!